# Kubeadm init hung on [init] This might take a minute or longer if the control plane images have to be pulled

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, google-kubernetes-engine

My intallation is hung in this step

```
kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=198.168.56.101 --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16

--- Kubeadm init stuck on [init] This might take a minute or longer if the control plane images have to be pulled.
```

Comment: For how long it is stuck? it is never going forwrd>?

Comment: clean it up and start it using `kubeadm init ` only

Comment: Hi, thanks it worked.. :) i just reset and ran with "kubeadm init"

Comment: ok then i will add it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean it up and start it using `kubeadm init` only, and let it chose the subnets itself.